# Is there a function in the Haskell standard library that replaces an item in a list?

Tags: haskell

I want a function `f :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]` where the return value is the third argument with the item at the index given by the first argument replaced by the second argument.

So

```
f 1 42 [1, 2, 3] == [1, 42, 3]
```

I looked on Hoogle for functions with that signature but didn't find any that matched what I was looking for.

Is there a function that does what I'm looking for in the Haskell standard library?

Comment: I don't think `base` has such a function. You could define it: `f i x = zipWith (\j y -> if i == j then x else y) [0..]`.

Comment: `splitAt` comes very close.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nope, no such function. Additionally, wanting this is a bad sign; consider using a more suitable data structure than lists if you frequently need indexing.

Comment: Can you expand on why you think that wanting this is a bad sign? If it makes a difference, my lists will always be of length 2, 3, or 4.

Comment: @TW80000 Indexing is slow; rebuilding a list after a change like you're proposing is slow. For small lists, maybe it's not a big deal; but even so, if you know your lists will always have size 2, 3, or 4, I think the idiomatic thing would be to create a new type that embodies that invariant.

Answer (score 1):

Since your lists are short, the repeated indexing could have tolerable performance.

A function to replace a value at a given index and immediately bail out, reusing the rest of the list, can be written as simply as simply

```
replix :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
replix i x xs | i >= 0 = let (h,_:t) = splitAt i xs
                         in h ++ [x] ++ t
```

with the use of the built-in [`splitAt :: Int -> [a] -> ([a], [a])`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:splitAt).

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`lens`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library:

```hs
import Control.Lens

f :: Int -> a -> [a] -> [a]
f i = set (ix i)
```